# Why am I getting a "cannot find symbol" error here in Eclipse, when it's all in the project directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I'm getting the following error in Eclipse, when I try to run a Batch file via the External Tools feature (in the Run menu).

:

```
C:\Eclipse_Java\AutonomicUsingJMX\adelthesis\src\fixedMessageApp>cd C:\Eclipse_Java\AutonomicUsingJMX\adelthesis\src\fixedMessageApp 

C:\Eclipse_Java\AutonomicUsingJMX\adelthesis\src\fixedMessageApp>javac -cp commons-io-2.4.jar FixedMessageSequenceServer.java 
FixedMessageSequenceServer.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    private FixedMessageSequenceProtocol fmsp;
```

This is my batch file :

```
cd C:\Eclipse_Java\AutonomicUsingJMX\adelthesis\src\fixedMessageApp 
javac -cp commons-io-2.4.jar FixedMessageSequenceServer.java   
java  FixedMessageSequenceClient.java 
java FixedMessageSequenceClient 
pause  
echo finished
```

But everything is in one project folder within Eclipse :

[image]

Any clues on what is going wrong with my code ?  I'm thinking my batch file is incorrect, but not sure

Comment: What is the code that calls the batch file?

Comment: @kevingreen  - Actually, there is none, the batch is just used to kick off the whole Client/Server application externally via the `Run` --> `External Tools`  menu

Comment: seems you missed the jar of that file ?

Comment: @kevingreen - thanks though , I could use something like  `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mybatch.bat");`

Comment: @suresh - not sure I follow you , `commons-io-2.4.jar ` is in there

Comment: The "cannot find symbol" error is a compilation error. What happens when you run the batch lines individually?

Comment: @kevingreen - ah you're right, I'm getting same error in CMD

Answer (score 1):

Cannot find symbol is a compilation error. Check the commands individually to see which one is having the problem.

See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706217/288915